# can we set height of bx warppper according to slide content

Tags: jquery, bxslider

can we set the height of bx slider according to slide content?

as if now i have 3 images one by one in a slide and another slide has only one image so its getting lots of empty space in the one image slide.
here i am pasting my code:

```
<div class="slider">                
              <ul class="bxslider-two">
                <li>
                <div class="caption1 top_caption">
                <h4 class="section-title">Group Show </h4>
                <p class="font_11">London: 24 Grafton Street / September 5 - October 3, 2015 </p>
                </div>

                <a class="group1" href="images/WDP_6372.jpg" title=""><img src="images/WDP_6372.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <a class="group1" href="images/WDP_6375.jpg" title=""><img src="images/WDP_6375.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <a class="group1" href="images/WDP_6376.jpg" title=""><img src="images/WDP_6376.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <div class="caption1"> 
                    <span>Chittrovanu Mazumdar, The Other Face, 2015. Acrylic on canvas, 100 x 100 cm, Edition 1 of 4 <span class="pull-right download_catelog"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa fa-download"></i>Download CV</a></span></span>
                    <a href="">Request Information >></a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div class="caption1 top_caption">
                <h4 class="section-title">Group Show </h4>
                <p class="font_11">London: 24 Grafton Street / September 5 - October 3, 2015 </p>
                </div>
                <a class="group1" href="images/DSC_0044.jpg" title=""><img src="images/DSC_0044.jpg" alt=""></a>

                <div class="caption1"> 
                    <span>Chittrovanu Mazumdar, The Other Face, 2015. Acrylic on canvas, 100 x 100 cm, Edition 1 of 4 <span class="pull-right download_catelog"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa fa-download"></i>Download CV</a></span></span>
                    <a href="">Request Information >></a>
                  </div>
                </li>


              </ul>
            </div>
```

can some help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct my if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're trying to achieve more of a ticker approach (continuous image scrolling all with their own links).

Perhaps try [BXSlider's 'Ticker Mode'](http://bxslider.com/examples/ticker) to avoid the spacing issue. You can set the speed but customisation is not as detailed.

If this isn't what you're looking for then try a multi-item content slider [such as this](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Otherwise, you will need to be more specific about what you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using adaptiveHeight option.

```
$('.bxslider-two').bxSlider({
   adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

Some bxslider examples (http://bxslider.com/examples).
There is setting for slideshow using 
adaptiveHeight (http://bxslider.com/examples/slideshow-adaptive-height)